# Removing utm_* parameters from URL in javascript with a regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, url, clean-urls

I did not find any good answer to this question so I share what I found and works

if you want to remove all the google analytics terms from an URL, you mostly want to keep the other parameters and get a clean valid URL at the end

```
url = url.replace(/(\&|\?)utm([_a-z0-9=+\-]+)/igm, "$1");
```

with a url like this
`https://www.somewebsite.fr/produit/yi-camera-3600-noir-vr-33705370/offre-81085802?utm_source=325483&utm_medium=affiliation&utm_content=catalogue-RDC&awc=6901_1530705916_88ef12642ad61dfc5239ba01bbbe5249`

you will get this `https://www.somewebsite.fr/produit/yi-camera-3600-noir-vr-33705370/offre-81085802?&&&awc=6901_1530705916_88ef12642ad61dfc5239ba01bbbe5249`

this url is already valid but we have some dupe & signs
if you remove the $1 from the first request you will with only a & sign and not the ? that you should have in the beginning

so next clean up we keep the first ? sign => $1 and remove the other leading &

```
url = url.replace(/(\?)\&+/igm, "$1");
```

here we have a nice clean URL

full version :

```
url = url.replace(/(\&|\?)utm([_a-z0-9=+\-]+)/igm, "$1");
url = url.replace(/(\?)\&+/igm, "$1");
```

if you can find a one liner you're welcome

Edit : the resulting URL should be this one : https://www.somewebsite.fr/produit/yi-camera-3600-noir-vr-33705370/offre-81085802?awc=6901_1530705916_88ef12642ad61dfc5239ba01bbbe5249

Comment: What would be the resulting correct url?

Comment: Good point I have edited my question

Comment: @benraay `/(?<=&|\?)utm_.*?(&|$)/igm` does not remove the trailing `?` if the query string only contains `utm` params. It is also not portable across JS environments that do not support ECMAScript 2018 standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it could be as simple as:
`url = url.replace(/(?<=&|\?)utm_.*?(&|$)/igm, "");`

You do not need to escape `&`

`(?<=&|\?)` = positive lookbehind

`.*?` = everything, but "not greedy"

Comment: very nice also more strong on parameter values ! thanks

Comment: Note it contains a lookbehind that is only supported by ECMAScript 2018 compatible JS environments. Also, it does not remove the trailing `?` if the query string only contains `utm` params. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/TCHjRU/1). `https://www.somewebsite.fr/produit/yi-camera-3600-noir-vr-33705370/offre-81085802?utm=6901_1530705916_88ef12642ad61dfc5239ba01bbbe5249&utm=ewe` ends up as `https://www.somewebsite.fr/produit/yi-camera-3600-noir-vr-33705370/offre-81085802?`.

Comment: exactly I didn't know that my need is for node js 8 and it works fine with that version

Comment: @benraay Do you mean it is OK for you that [`https://www.some.fr/812?utm=6901&utm=ewe` becomes `https://www.some.fr/812?`](https://regex101.com/r/TCHjRU/2)?

Comment: @benraay Ok, I think I misinterpreted the goal then. You said that `https://www.some.fr/812?&&aws=true` is already OK, and I thought you wanted as cleanly-looking pattern as possible.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes the first on is already ok, the purpose is to scrape informations on that page after this cleaning but the url is visible to people, "?&&&" is a bit ugly one "?" sign at the end looks ok

Answer (score 3):

You may use a single regex compatible with all JS versions that will

- match and capture `?` that is followed by 1 or more `utm` param that are followed with a param other than `utm` one and replace with `$1` to restore that `?` since it is necessary
- or, match any `?` with 1 or more `utm` params in the query string where no params other than `utm` are present (so, `$1` will be empty, and `?` will get removed)
- or, just match all `utm` params to remove them.

The regex will look like

```
.replace(/(\?)utm[^&]*(?:&utm[^&]*)*&(?=(?!utm[^\s&=]*=)[^\s&=]+=)|\?utm[^&]*(?:&utm[^&]*)*$|&utm[^&]*/gi, '$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/36JLne/1)

**Details**

- `(\?)utm[^&]*(?:&utm[^&]*)*&(?=(?!utm[^\s&=]*=)[^\s&=]+=)` - `?utm` (with `?` inside a capturing group later referenced with `$1`), 0+ chars other than `&`, and then 0 or more repetitions of `&utm` followed with 0+ chars other than `&` and then a `&` that is followed with 0+ chars other than whitespace, `&` and `=` and then `=` that is not `utm` param
- `|` - or
- `\?utm[^&]*(?:&utm[^&]*)*$` - `?utm`, 0+ chars other than `&`, and then 0 or more repetitions of `&utm` followed with 0+ chars other than `&` and then the end of the string
- `|` - or
- `&utm[^&]*` - a `&`, `utm` and then 0+ chars other than `&`

JS demo:

```js
var urls = ['https://www.somewebsite.fr/produit/yi-camera-3600-noir-vr-33705370/offre-81085802?utm_source=325483&utm_medium=affiliation&utm_content=catalogue-RDC&awc=6901_1530705916_88ef12642ad61dfc5239ba01bbbe5249', 'https://www.somewebsite.fr/produit/yi-camera-3600-noir-vr-33705370/offre-81085802?t=55&utm_source=325483&utm_medium=affiliation&utm_content=catalogue-RDC&awc=6901_1530705916_88ef12642ad61dfc5239ba01bbbe5249','https://www.somewebsite.fr/produit/yi-camera-3600-noir-vr-33705370/offre-81085802?awc=6901_1530705916_88ef12642ad61dfc5239ba01bbbe5249&utm_tt=78', 'https://www.somewebsite.fr/produit/yi-camera-3600-noir-vr-33705370/offre-81085802?utm=6901_1530705916_88ef12642ad61dfc5239ba01bbbe5249&utm=ewe'];

var u = 'utm[^&]*';
var rx = new RegExp("(\\?)"+u+"(?:&"+u+")*&(?=(?!utm[^\s&=]*=)[^\s&=]+=)|\\?"+u+"(?:&"+u+")*$|&"+u, "ig");
for (var url of urls) {
  console.log(url, "=>", url.replace(rx, '$1'));
}
```

Comment: really nice and detailed solution but the readability is a bit lost, I prefer my first two liner version it's much more easy to understand

Comment: @benraay The readability is lost, true, however, it embraces all possible scenarios and shows how to build the pattern dynamically. The solution can be tailored to remove other params easily, and it can be used with regex libraries that do not support lookbehinds, like VBA or JS versions that do not support ECMAScript 2018 standard.